# ValueError: Invalid character found in sheet title

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

This Python code fails:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.create_sheet('*nice*')
```

Exception:

```
/home/foo/local/bin/python /home/foo/src/invalid.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/src/invalid.py", line 5, in <module>
    sheet = wb.create_sheet('*nice')
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 158, in create_sheet
    new_ws = Worksheet(parent=self, title=title)
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 121, in __init__
    _WorkbookChild.__init__(self, parent, title)
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/child.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.title = title or self._default_title
  File "/home/foo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/child.py", line 93, in title
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid character * found in sheet title
```

How to create a sheet containing `*` in the title?

Comment: According to the OOXML specification you are not allowed to use * in worksheet names which is why openpyxl raises the exception.

Comment: @CharlieClark no way to escape/quote these characters?

Comment: What is unclear about "not allowed"? See 18.17.2.3 of the specification for details.

Comment: @CharlieClark the reason is not clear. I don't understand why some characters are not allowed.

Comment: The specification forbids the use of some characters in worksheet names. EOM

Comment: @CharlieClark you say "EOM". I think that's "open source spirit" vs "closed source spirit". I am very happy to see one of these spirits, the one I like more, being more successful then the other (my point of view).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex to replace the invalid characters:

```
import re

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.workbook.child import INVALID_TITLE_REGEX

wb = Workbook()
title = re.sub(INVALID_TITLE_REGEX, '_', '*nice*')
sheet = wb.create_sheet(title)
```

But this is not a solution, just a work-around.

Better solutions are welcome: Is there a way to quote the `*`?

Comment: This is the best answer since it imports the pattern directly from openpyxl.

Comment: This is a misuse of the `re` library, `INVALID_TITLE_REGEX` is already compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Can we create a worksheet using asterisk (*) symbol ?

```
sheet = wb.create_sheet("&nice")
```

According to [this](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/seven-characters-you-cant-use-in-worksheet-names) , we cant use following special characters in the worksheet names

\
/
*
[
]
:
?

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` has a compiled regex for handling invalid characters:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.workbook.child import INVALID_TITLE_REGEX

raw_title = "A*B*C"
title = INVALID_TITLE_REGEX.sub(' ', raw_title)

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.create_sheet(title)
```

Here's the regex definition:

```
>>> INVALID_TITLE_REGEX
re.compile(r'[\\*?:/\[\]]', re.UNICODE)
```